# How is the Django view class executed?

Tags: django, class, url

I have a simple question to ask. How is the class executed defined the views.py? For example, if I have the path defined like the following, I assume that the snippet, 'views.PostListView.as_view()', is executing the PostListView defined in the views.py. Am I right?

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
path('post/<int:pk>', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py (which is the base View class for generic views that all of your other views would generally inherit from), as_view is defined as a class/static method of the base view class, and it specifically returns a function **view** (`def view(request, *args, **kwargs)` ), which in turn takes a request object and then multipe optional args/kwargs.  This view function is what gets passed to the urlpatterns.  When an actual request comes in from the user, Django walks through the urlpatterns until it finds a match, and will then pass the request object and other information to the actual view function (so it gets executed once per matching request).

Hope that helps.